# Solution for shared home directory across separate machines - change $HOME variable?

Tags: linux, unix, environment-variables, shared-libraries

I have an account on a set of machines which have separate processors, memory, and storage but share the same home directory. So, for instance, if I ssh into either machine, they will both source the same `bashrc` file.

The sysadmin does not install all of the software I wish to use so I have compiled some from source and store it in `bin`, `lib`, etc. directories in the home directory and change my `PATH`, `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` variables to include these. Each machine, at least up until recently, had different operating systems (or at least versions) installed and I was told that compiled code on one machine would not necessarily give the same result on the other. Therefore my (very hacky) solution was the following:

- Create two directories in $HOME: `~/server1home` and `~/server2home`,
  each with their own set of `bin`, `lib`, etc. with separately
  compiled libraries.
- Edit my `.bashrc` to check which server I am on and set the path variables to look in the correct directories for binaries and libraries for the server.

Lately, we moved building and the servers were rebooted and I believe they both run the same OS now. Most of my setup was broken by the reboot so I have to remake it. In principle, I don't need anything different on each machine and they could be identical apart from the fact that there are more processors and memory to run code on. They don't have the same hardware, as far as I'm aware, so I still don't know if they can safely run the same binaries. Is such a setup safe to run code that needs to be numerically precise?

Alternatively, I would redo my hack differently this time. I had a lot of dotfiles that still ended up going into `$HOME`, rather than my `serverXhome` directories and the situation was always a little messy. I want to know if it's possible to redefine `$HOME` on login, based on `hostname` and then have nothing but the two `serverXhome` directories inside the shared $HOME, with everything duplicated inside each of these new home directories. Is this possible to set up without administrative privileges? I imagine I could make a .profile script that runs on login and changes `$HOME` to point at the right directory and then sources the new `.bashrc` within that directory to set all the rest of the environment variables. Is this the correct way of going about this or are there some pitfalls to be wary of?

**TL;DR:** I have the same home directory for two separate machines. Do binary libraries and executables compiled on one machine run safely on the other? Otherwise, is there a strategy to redefine `$HOME` on each machine to point to a subdirectory of the shared home directory and have separate binaries for each?

PS: I'm not sure if this is more relevant in superuser stackexchange or not. Please let me know if I'd have better luck posting there.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Answer (score 1):

If the two machines have the same processor architecture, in general compiled binaries should work on both.

Now there is a number of factors that come into play, and the result will hugely depend on the type of programs that you want to run, but in general, if the same shared libraries are installed, then your programs will work identically.

On different distributions, or different versions of a given distribution, it is likely that the set of installed libraries, or that the version of them will differ, which means that your programs will work on the machine on which they are built, but probably not on another one.

If you can control how they are built, you can rebuild your applications to have static linkage instead of dynamic, which means that they will embed all the libraries they need when built, resulting in a much bigger executable, but providing a much improved compatibility.

If the above doesn't work and you need to use a different set of programs for each machine, I would recommend leaving the `$HOME` environment variable alone, and only change your `$PATH` depending on the machine you are on.

You can have a short snipper in your `.bashrc` like so:

```
export PATH=$HOME/$(hostname)/bin:$PATH
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$HOME/$(hostname)/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

Then all you need is a folder bearing the machine's hostname for each machine you can connect to. If several machines share the same operating system and architecture, making symbolic links will save you some space.

Comment: Thanks! It seems static linking is a good option to play it safe. Though I can ask the sysadmin if they intend to keep the library versions the same. Can you explain why you recommend leaving $HOME alone?